# Metric to combine average with number of accurance

Tags: dataset, bigdata, metric

I was analysing a dataset which has got two main columns which I can name like:

category:String
amount: Int

So I wanted to know the average of amount for each of the category. So I did something like:

```
df.groupBy("category").agg(avg("amount") as average)
```

The problem is for categories I don't have many observations, sometimes just one or two. But for other categories I have around 5000.

So I would like to know if there is any metrics where I can reflect that the average may be more or less accurate depending on the amount of observations used for the average.

Answer (score 2):

The metric you are looking for is the standard error. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error):

> the standard error equals the standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size.

So as the sample size increases the standard error decreases. You can also see [this](https://www.quora.com/As-sample-size-increases-why-does-the-standard-deviation-of-results-get-smaller-Can-someone-please-provide-a-simple-math-example-and-explain-why) for an explanation with some code in R.